# Open generic type cannot be resolved with autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

Heres my setup code:

```
Dim builder As New ContainerBuilder
Dim assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast(Of Assembly).ToArray

builder.RegisterModule(Of AutofacWebTypesModule)
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies).AsClosedTypesOf(GetType(IGenericRepository(Of)))

'Controllers
builder.RegisterControllers(assemblies)

'Model Binders
builder.RegisterModelBinders(assemblies)
builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider()

Dim container = builder.Build
```

And controller code:

```
Public Class TestController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Public Sub New(manager As IGenericRepository(Of TestObject))

    End Sub

    Public Function Test() As ContentResult

        Return Content("OK")

    End Function

End Class
```

Now when i navigate to `/Test/Test` I get the following error:

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProject.TestController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProject.IGenericRepository`1[MyProject.TestObject] manager' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProject.IGenericRepository`1[MyProject.TestObject])'.

What is the proper way to register this open generic with autofac?

I cant use something like `builder.RegisterGeneric(GetType(GenericRepository(Of))).As(GetType(IGenericRepository(Of)))` because the concrete class is in a different, unreferenced project

Comment: does `assemblies` contains the assembly with your concrete implementation ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand yes it is.  So i have realized i can get a reference to the type I need by searching that array, thank you for pointing that out. Added my solution as an anwser. Still curious if this is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AsClosedTypesOf` method will register closed type (not generic) that implement the specific open type.

Your code will work if one assembly contains a closed implementation of `IGenericRepository<TestObject>`

```
public class TestRespository : IGenericRepository<TestObject> 
{ }
```

In your case you want to register an open generic, without assembly scanning it is done by using

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).As(typeof(IGenericRepository<>))
```

but due to limitation explained in this Github issue ([Support registering open generic types when scanning assemblies](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/215)) it is not  possible.

One common workaround is to do your own assembly scanning :

```
var repositories = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
{
    return t.GetTypeInfo()
        .ImplementedInterfaces.Any(
            i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IGenericRepository<>));
});

foreach (var repository in repositories)
{
    builder.RegisterGeneric(repository).As(typeof(IGenericRepository<>));
}
```

Comment: Sorry for C# let me know if you want me to convert the code in VB.net

Answer (score 0):

[Cyril](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814735/cyril-durand) helped me realize that the `assemblies` array contains the type i want to use. So I was able to workaround with this:

```
Dim genericType = assemblies.Single(Function(x) x.FullName.Contains("OtherAssembly")).
     DefinedTypes.        
     Single(Function(x) x.FullName.Contains("GenericRepository"))
builder.RegisterGeneric(genericRepo.UnderlyingSystemType).As(GetType(IGenericRepository(Of)))
```